# How sort KeyValuePair with collection

Tags: c#-4.0

Here Product has following properies

1. ID
2. Label
3. GUID
4. RDate

Following code is not working

```
 rtn.Sort(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, List<Product>> h1, KeyValuePair<string, List<Product>> h2)
 {
                return h1.Value.Label.CompareTo(h2.Value.Label);
 });
```

Comment: Could you clarify "not working"? What happens when you try the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message, and if so, which?

Comment: `Value` is a `List`, how do you want to sort the "outer" list according to the "inner" list, all the more if `Label` is a string?

Comment: Okay where did the keyvaluepair come from. What class is rtn?

Comment: I do believe he means not working as in doesn't compile. Unless List<Product>, is not List<T> ??